# C++ Compiler Driver Has Stopped Working

Tags: c++, sdk

I've downloaded platform SDK and tried using it with Visual Studio 2005. Every time I say built solution it says `C++ compiler driver has stopped working!`, I also installed Visual Studio 2008, and still face the same problem. this is what it says on the log file,

> Compiling...
>
> Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741515 returned from 'C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\cl.exe'.

What do I do?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're receiving?

Answer (score 1):

-1073741515 is the DWORD equivalent of 0xc0000135 which from googling it seems to be related to not having .NET installed, so you may want to try downloading and installing the latest .NET framework.

If that doesn't work then you might try the following to debug the problem a bit further.

Visual Studio usually installs a short-cut on the Start Menu called something like Visual Tools/Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt - run this and then enter cl.exe and you should see something like the following:

```
> cl.exe
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

If not then you might want to download the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and run it from the same command shell window as above, then in DW open the cl.exe from your VS installation (vc\bin\cl.exe). Check if all the DLL's are found (ignore msjava.dll).

Comment: Why can we ignore msjava.dll?

Comment: msjava.dll always gets reported as missing. See the dependency walker FAQ (http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need to install the platform SDK along with Visual Studio ? VS comes with everything you need to compile your code on the .NET platform. If you still have that problem, may be you should reinstall visual studio ?

Comment: For what it's worth, that's been my experience too; whenever I install visual studio on a new dev machine, I need to download the platform SDK separately.